# Yet another UTF-8, PHP and Ajax post

Tags: php, utf-8

I've tried to solve an issue with character encoding for many days now without finding any solution.

Here's what's happening:

I have a form in a page.
When I copy paste a text from Adobe Reader to this form, everything goes fine.
When I copy paste a text from Preview (mac os image viewer), it turns into strange characters.

When the form is submitted, the sentence:
salade mêlée, tomates, mozzarella, basilic melon en saison et jambon cru

Goes through an ajax function and I can see in firebug:

```
salade%20me%CC%82le%CC%81e%2C%20tomates%2C%20mozzarella%2C%20basilic%20melon%20en%20saison%20et%20jambon%20cru
```

Now when I get this value into my Zend Controller, in order to save it to my database, I meet the following cases:

if i iconv it to cp1252, the text is cut to "salade me" and that's it
If if utf8_encode it transforms into: salade meÌleÌe, tomates, mozzarella, basilic melon en saison et jambon cru

If I utf8_decode it, it goes to: salade me?le?e, tomates, mozzarella, basilic melon en saison et jambon cru

If I do no transformation, it works...but in phpmyadmin i see: salade mÃªlÃ©e, tomates, mozzarella, basilic melon en saison et jambon cru

Any idea to help me? I'm turning crazy!!

Thanks!

Comment: Whats the encoding of your database? Is it latin-1?

Comment: try to add `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` at top of your php file (c'est toujours la galère avec le français!)

Comment: Why not use UTF-8 everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that phpMyAdmin is configured to use UTF-8, and that the database is also using UTF-8, as well as the connection between PHP and the database. If all of them are using UTF-8, then you should have no issues passing UTF-8 back and forth.